# Application stops receiving data from remote machine

Tags: vb.net, ssh, remote-server

I am developing an app in VB.NET that connects to a remote Linux server to execute a task; my application sends input data for the server program, starts the execution in the server and retrieves output information from the server when the command execution is done. I use Renci SSH.NET to exchange files (SFTP) and monitor the remote server (SSH). One of the critical tasks is to detect when the remote machine finishes command execution, and depending on the input this can take between 5 minutes and many hours.

Here is my problem: for short runs (5 minutes or less), the application runs smoothly, no problems whatsoever. But, when the execution of the remote command takes more than 10 minutes, my application does not detect any response from the server and just hangs, since it never receives the indication from the server that the remote task is finished. I use the Renci.SshNet.Common.Stream.DataAvailable property to detect when the command is done by testing if the shell prompt string is present when I invoke Stream.Read().

Now, I know that the problem is the app, since when I execute the remote code "manually" (logging into the server with a terminal app and executing the command) it finishes without problems. I suspect it has something to do with the way Renci ShellStream object polls the remote machine for data. Any ideas as to what might be happening? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your TCP connection to the server might be through some kind of NAT device or stateful firewall which is dropping the TCP connection when it's idle for too long. You might need to ensure that some traffic is going through the SSH connection every few minutes. I'm not a C# developer so I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: I am not familiar with that library and you have not shared any code but Kenster may be right. Could be a **keepalive** problem. This is your keyword. I would have a look at the library, maybe a keepalive feature is already implemented. Otherwise you have to come up with your own solution to keep the tunnel open. Merely sending a ping to the server at regular intervals might do the job.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen, for your insights. I suspect you are right with the Firewall/NAT theory since I started having this problem when I started to try to execute from my home computer (damn you, Covid-19). I found on the lousy Renci documentation a method call KeepAliveInterval, which I think does exactly what you describe, pining the server to avoid setting the connection idle. I will try setting this interval to 2-3 minutes upon connection and see if that helps.